# How to set Artifactory password in maven settings.xml

Tags: xml, maven, artifactory

I have a Maven project that I can run `mvn clean install` on, and it builds locally just fine.

I've since created a JFrog Artifactory server that I'd like to use to manage this project's artifacts.

My problem is that I don't know how to properly set the password in my `settings.xml`'s `<server>` block.

I've created a Maven repository in Artifactory and selected the "set me up" option for the `libs-release-local` repository, which automatically generates the following `settings.xml` file (which I copied and pasted in `~/.m2/settings.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
      <id>libs-snapshot</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

When this file was autogenerated, an auth token was also autogenerated for me in the Artifactory UI -- which is confusing because no context was given on what to do with this token. So I'm not sure if this is the password I should be using.

Additionally, the password field in the auto-generated settings.xml suggests that I need to base64-encode my plaintext password, and reference it within the `<password>` tags, but I'm not sure what the correct process for base64 encoding my password is.

I've set the `<username>` tag to hold my plaintext username, and the `<password>` tag to hold my plaintext password but this returns a 401 error. I've also base64 encoded my plaintext password and set that as the password, but get the same error:

```bash
[INFO] Artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.1 is present in the local repository, but cached from a remote repository ID that is unavailable in current build context, verifying that is downloadable from [libs-snapshot (http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot, default, releases+snapshots)]
Downloading from libs-snapshot: http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.1/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.1.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ line 35, column 22
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.vismark:MicroServiceOne:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.1 (present, but unavailable): Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.1 from/to libs-snapshot (http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot): status code: 401, reason phrase:  (401) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.vismark:MicroServiceOne:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/Users/mc98763/Documents/GitHub/Personal/MicroServiceOne/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.vismark:MicroServiceOne:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.1 (present, but unavailable): Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.1 from/to libs-snapshot (http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot): status code: 401, reason phrase:  (401) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I've also added the following `distributionManagement` block to my `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>5fb7025f605d-releases</name>
            <url>http://ec2-3-92-61-201.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

What is the proper was to set the password in the `settings.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

The "security.getCurrentUsername" is a [filtered resource](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/filtered-resources), once you will download (instead of copying) the settings.xml snippet it should be populated with a username and an encrypted password.

If you would like to encrypt the password yourself you can use Maven's [Password Encryption](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Comment: When I download the settings.xml file, I don't see any username be auto-populated, but I see the following as the password -- is this correct?: `<password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"cmVmdGtuOjAxOjE3MzAxODc2NDE6eGdqNDZtZDZRalMwbGRhN1Y4ellTVVV2SnQw"}</password>`.

Comment: Doesn't look correct, should be just the encrypted password and look like this:     `<server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>notarealencryptedpassword</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>`